# Is it safe to mark contact emails as "on_hold" in bulk with a direct database query?

Tags: civimail

We've just now started getting bounce reports for our outgoing email, and the number of them is alarmingly high. The majority of the responses is: "The email account that you tried to reach does not exist" so it is just that our contact list is very out of date.

From a recent mailer, CiviCRM marked 200 as bounces but the external bounce report shows over a 1000. That is a *lot* to go through 1 by 1, so I was thinking of running a database query such as:

```
update civicrm_email SET on_hold = '1', hold_date = NOW() 
where email in ( 
 [list of email addresses]
)
```

Is this an ill-advised thing to do? Is the on_hold information tracked elsewhere also that might cause a conflict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to update the email in civicrm to on-hold.

Comment: Oh, I think you misread my question. I want to mark around 1000 addresses as On Hold; I don't want to remove them from hold!

Comment: Ahh sorry, updated the answer

Comment: Terrific, thanks!